# SyntaxError in "from keras.utils import to_categorical"

Tags: python, keras, syntax-error

[image]
I have a problem when I try to run the code which is about a Relation Extraction. My environment is Python2.7.17. The version of python extention in VScode is 2022.2.1924087327.
I dont know why it occurs SyntaxError. When I search the problem about `from keras.utils import to_categorical`, almost all the answer is to change it into `from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical`. But it is different from My problem.
Can anybody help me?

When I want to run the code in Python 2.7.17 not 3.7, what should I do?

Comment: [I downvoted because… an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Can you specify Keras and Tensorflow versions?

Comment: It's likely an issue of Python 2.7, which has been deprecated for about a decade

Comment: my Keras version is 2.10.0

Comment: It's my first time to ask a question on the web, I will show more details and present my code next time. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `keras` with neither Python==2 nor Python<3.6 because `keras` use f-strings:

```
In [1]: from keras.utils import to_categorical
  File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/distribute/sidecar_evaluator.py", line 195
    f"{_CHECKPOINT_TIMEOUT_SEC} seconds. "
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```